# Opening an Angular Material Dialog containing a Mat-Table causes the dialog to appear without any content

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to open an angular material dialog populated with a mat-table containing a list of orders.

When I call the method openOrderDetailsDialog(), the dialog opens up, but it does not contain the mat-table at first. It is an empty dialog.

Sometimes I am required to click the empty dialog that opens up to make the mat-table appear inside the dialog, and sometimes this happens automatically after about one second.

I have not been able to define what's causing this problem and would really appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks alot in advance,

component.html

```
<div class="dialog-content">
    <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="customerNumber">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>CustomerNumber</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.customerNumber}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="customerName">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>CustomerName</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.customerName}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="orderNumber">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>OrderNumber</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.orderNumber}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="orderAmount">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>OrderAmount</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.orderAmount}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
        </mat-row>
    </mat-table>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'order-details',
    templateUrl: './order-details.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./order-details.component.scss']
})
export class OrderDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
    displayedColumns = ['customerNumber', 'customerName', 'orderNumber', 'orderAmount'];
    dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Order>;
    @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

    constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<OrderDetailsComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: { orders: Order[] }) {
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
         }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataSource.data = this.data.orders;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }
```

Method on other component that opens the dialog:

```
openOrderDetailsDialog(event: any) {`enter code here`
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(OrderDetailsComponent,
        {
            panelClass: 'mat-dialog-md',
            data: { orders: event.target.data.orders }
        });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried initiating the dataSource inside the ngOnInit?

ngOnInit() {
   this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data.orders);
   this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}

Comment: Thank you Lars,

This seems to have done the trick :)

Comment: You're welcome 

Comment: Unfortunately I was wrong. It worked most of the times, but sometimes the same problem occurs. I have not been able to reproduce the issue in stackblitz. But maybe there's a way to get around this problem? Because when the dialog opens, it sometimes needs to be clicked to get populated with the data. Is there a way to accomplish this when the component initializes?